# Multi user signin on JupyterHub

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyterhub

I'm trying to setup JupyterHub on an Amazon EC2 instance using [these instructions](https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub).

In the step titled **Run the Hub Server** I'm running the server using `sudo jupyterhub`. But I'm not able to login using the credentials of other Linux users (those apart from the one used to run the server).

It says *No such file or directory: 'jupyterhub-singleuser'* in the logs and I get a 500 internal server error in the browser. Please help!

Answer (score 4):

Here's how to set up jupyterhub for use with multi-users:

My github here will help you.

[Github/Jupyter](https://github.com/Nouvellie/ubuntu/blob/ubuntu/contents/jupyter.md)

Create a group:

```
$ sudo groupadd <groupname>
```

Add a user to a group:

```
$ sudo adduser <username> <groupname>
```

Using:

```
c.LocalAuthenticator.group_whitelist = ['<groupname>']
```

Comment: you just saved me a lot of time. appreciated dear stranger.

Answer (score 3):

It's been a long time since you asked this, but I think a I can help other users that have similar problems.

I think the problem is that `jupyterhub-singleuser` is not in PATH for all users. The solution I used was to make symbolic links for the binaries jupyterhub requires.

```
sudo ln -s /your/jupyterhub/install/location/jupyterhub /usr/bin/jupyterhub
sudo ln -s /your/jupyterhub/install/location/configurable-http-proxy /usr/bin/configurable-http-proxy
sudo ln -s /your/jupyterhub/install/path/node /usr/bin/node
sudo ln -s /your/jupyterhub/install/path/jupyterhub-singleuser /usr/bin/jupyterhub-singleuser
```

I think it will work